# What are these rocks

Tags: mineralogy

[image][image] 
This Crystal has a couple gas bubbles and impurities in the very center of it it breaks only one way it is 4720 carats very beautiful very hard

Comment: I live in Oregon I traded a couple crystals for this rock because I thought it was really awesome never seen something like this before he said that it came from Brazil

Comment: Please read our guide https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/125/94 for rock identification questions. Inparticular the photographs are out of focus!

Comment: Hard to tell anything from the out of focus pictures, but the concoidal fracture and colour suggests man-made glass to me...

Answer (score 4):

looks like a broken block of glass from a glass factory, called glass slag or chunk glass, you can get a whole range of hardness and color depending on what type of glass they were making. People often use it to make art.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Definitely looks like broken, human-made glass. The presence of bubbles pretty much clinches it.